# Tools Link Missing

Tags: support, status-bydesign

Anyone else missing the tools link in the header bar since the UI change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the site going fully live the reputation privileges have changed. From the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) they are:

> 15     Vote up
>   15   Flag offensive
>   50   Leave comments†
>   100  Edit community wiki posts
>   125  Vote down
>   150  Create new tags
>   200  Reduced advertising
>   200  Retag questions
>   250  Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions
>   1000     Show total up and down vote counts
>   2000     Edit other people's posts
>   3000     Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions
>   **10000  Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools**

(with added emphasis)

You can check your (new) progress to each level at the [privileges page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges).

Answer (score 3):

You need to have 10k points to see the tools again.